# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209) instead of response.statusCode == 404

Tags: flutter, http

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void getData() async {
    print('getData called');
    //                       Q is not a typo
    String urlString = 'http://Qsamples.openweathermap.org/';
    var url = Uri.parse(urlString);
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('statusCode = 200');
    } else {
      print('statusCode != 200');
    }
  }
```

When I make a request to the valid URL everything works like a charm. But when I change it to invalid I get

> E/flutter (19828): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]
> Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed host lookup:
> 'qsamples.openweathermap.org' (OS Error: No address associated with
> hostname, errno = 7)

instead of receiving `response.statusCode == 404`.

Here there is an example from library's authors where they are advising the same https://pub.dev/packages/http/example

Answer (score 1):

[image]

the urlString you used is not working.The urlString will be : https://samples.openweathermap.org/ this one is working.

Comment: Edited topic name. I am expecting this URL not to work, but in a controlled way.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your url from :

> http://Qsamples.openweathermap.org/

To :

> http://samples.openweathermap.org/q

it should return 404 error

Comment: thats not able to as site not reachable